# Expo Permissions returns status of 'undetermined'

Tags: android, react-native, permissions, expo

In my react native app, I ask for permission to access the camera roll as so:

```
  getPermissionAsync = async () => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    if (status !== "granted") {
      alert("Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!");
    }
    await this.setState({ permission: status === "granted" });
  };

  _pickMedia = async (index, type) => {
    if (this.state.permission != true) {
      await this.getPermissionAsync();
    }
    if (this.state.permission == true) {
        // get image
      } catch (E) {
        console.log(E);
      }
    }
  };
```

This works as expected during testing, but for my published version on Google Play, status is returned as `undetermined` whether or not the user gives permission. What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the react-native-community@react-native-permissions to 2.0.0 solves the issue.
Refer : https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions/issues/295

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work - I'm using expo permissions